# Using substring while using reduce()

Tags: javascript, reduce

I am trying to get the total length from an array using reduce. But I encountered a problem when I saw that the length was prefixed by 'km'. So I am trying to remove(substring) the 'km', then add the length. Here's what I've done so far:

```
this.totalLength= this.roads.map((road) => road.distance)
  .reduce((prev, next) => prev + parseFloat(next.substring(2)));
```

It is working but it is not adding the second value of the array to the totalLength.

Here's the sample of the array:

```
[
  {
    "Id": "1",
    "distance": "Km12.20",
    "name": "Hwy1"
  },
  {
    "Id": "2",
    "distance": "Km19.60",
    "name": "Hwy2"
  }
]
```

Comment: Please may you share an example of the array?

Comment: [
  {
    "Id": "1",
    "distance": "Km12.20",
    "name": "Hwy1"
  },
  {
    "Id": "2",
    "distance": "Km19.60",
    "name": "Hwy2"
  }
]

Comment: `this.totalLength = this.roads.reduce((fin, itm) => fin + parseFloat(itm.distance.slice(2)), 0);` - we may avoid `.map` by operating on the `road` object directly. Also as pointed out by answers below, setting initial value of the 'aggregator' (ie, `fin` in the above, or `prev` in the question) to zero.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend searching for a float using regex if you think it may be prefixed or suffixed by any other text. You can use the regex `/(\d*\.)?\d+/` to do so.

Additionally, [`<Array>.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) takes an additional parameter for the starting value, so make sure to provide that.

```js
this.totalLength= this.roads.map((road) => road.distance)
  .reduce((prev, next) => prev + (parseFloat(next.match(/(\d*\.)?\d+/)[0])||0), 0);
```

Comment: To other prospective, future readers: please note that the regex is a good-fit for this question because the `distance` (logically-speaking) will typically be positive (or zero). Negative distance is not meaningful and will not be accounted-for by regex `/(\d*\.)?\d+/`

Answer (score 1):

What you did is almost correct. `reduce` also expects a second argument which is the initial value.

```js
const roads = [
  {
    "Id": "1",
    "distance": "Km12.20",
    "name": "Hwy1"
  },
  {
    "Id": "2",
    "distance": "Km19.60",
    "name": "Hwy2"
  }
]

roads
  .map((road) => road.distance)
  .reduce((prev, next) => prev + parseFloat(next.substring(2)), 0);
```

Comment: We may avoid the `.map` by simply doing: `roads.reduce((p, n) => p + parseFloat(n.distance.substring(2)), 0);`